# what are the methods "public override bool equals(object obj)" and "public override int gethashcode()" doing?

Tags: c#, methods, operator-overloading, overriding, gethashcode

I started to learn about Operator overloading, and in an example code that I found those two methods were (`public override bool equals(object obj)` and `public override int gethashcode()`). I didn't understand why they are there because when I dubugged this program, I didn't see that the compiler goes into them. I don't know what they are doing or what am I overriding.

Can someone please help me and explain it?

Comment: Is the documentation unclear?

Comment: Not really. If documentation is unclear for System.Object, i would rather not use documentation at all.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently went to the wrong one. Then I found the right one and it got cleared. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most types in .NET derive from the type `System.Object`, simply called `object` in C#. (E.g. interfaces don't, however their implementations do.)

`System.Object` declares the methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as well as other members. (Note: The case matters in C#). The types you create automatically inherit these methods.

The task of `Equals` is to compare an object to another. The default implementation for reference types is to compare the references. If you want to change this behavior, you will have to override this method.

`GetHashCode` calculates the hash code of an object and is used in hash tables. For instance the types `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and `HashSet<T>` make use of it.
See [Hashtable and Dictionary Collection Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz.aspx). If you override `Equals`, you have to override `GetHashCode` as well in order to keep consistency.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to first refer the documentation.

[Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) -> Determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.

> The type of comparison between the current instance and the obj parameter depends on whether the current instance is a reference type or a value type. If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.

[Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) -> Serves as a hash function for a particular type.

> A hash code is a numeric value that is used to identify an object during equality testing. It can also serve as an index for an object in a collection.
>   The GetHashCode method is suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures such as a hash table.

Why are they [overrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) >  All types in c# are derived from [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx). They are overrides to give capability to derive class to provide alternate/suitable implementation of these functions if needed. Otherwise default implementation (in [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) should be sufficient).